# result of std::sort does not fit the compare relation

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I'm having trouble with std::sort.

I have a bunch data and have implemented a `bool contains(const Pocket2D& other);` method so sort the data a .. b .. c so that a contains b and b contains c etc.
This method uses other libraries and yields some constraints and posting ist might not help. So I wrote a unittest to test it properly but I disagree with the result of `std::sort`.
My sorting call:

```
std::sort(
    result.begin(), result.end(), []( const auto& p1, const auto& p2 )
    {
        return std::get<0>( p1 ).contains( std::get<0>( p2 ) );
    } );
```

The (wrong) result is :

03.stp
33.stp
32.stp
25.stp
**26.stp**
**27.stp**
28.stp
29.stp
30.stp
31.stp
24.stp
04.stp
05.stp
06.stp
07.stp
08.stp
09.stp
17.stp
01.stp
**10.stp**
11.stp
12.stp
13.stp
14.stp
15.stp
16.stp
00.stp
18.stp
19.stp
02.stp
20.stp
21.stp
22.stp
23.stp

**(10 should be before 26/27 and not after)**

So I figured the contains method is **faulty**. BUT then I printed the whole `contains` relation inside the unittest and it looks right (I left out all contours that do not contain any other contour):

```
for ( auto& outerPocketTuple : result )
{
    for ( const auto innerPocketTuple : result )
    {
        if ( std::get<0>( outerPocketTuple ).contains( std::get<0>( innerPocketTuple ) ) )
        {
            std::get<2>( outerPocketTuple ).push_back( std::get<1>( innerPocketTuple ) );
        }
    }
}

for ( const auto& r : result )
{
    of << std::get<1>( r ) << ": ";
    for ( const auto& ri : std::get<2>( r ) )
    {
        of << ri << " ";
    }
    of << std::endl;
}

10.stp: 26.stp 27.stp 
03.stp: 00.stp 01.stp 10.stp 11.stp 12.stp 13.stp 
        14.stp 15.stp 16.stp 17.stp 18.stp 19.stp 
        02.stp 20.stp 21.stp 22.stp 23.stp 24.stp 
        25.stp 26.stp 27.stp 28.stp 29.stp 
        30.stp 31.stp 32.stp 33.stp 
        04.stp 05.stp 06.stp 07.stp 08.stp 09.stp 
32.stp: 02.stp 
33.stp: 00.stp 01.stp 10.stp 11.stp 12.stp 13.stp 
        14.stp 15.stp 16.stp 17.stp 18.stp 19.stp 
        02.stp 20.stp 21.stp 22.stp 23.stp 24.stp 
        25.stp 26.stp 27.stp 28.stp 29.stp 
        32.stp 
        04.stp 05.stp 06.stp 07.stp 08.stp 09.stp
```

I'm very sorry to post data instead of code but the code is extremely use case specific.

### My problem ist that the Comparator looks right but the result doesn't.

Here is my minimal example. The lambda `contains` pretty much does the same as the original culprit.

```
std::vector<size_t> test_data;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 34; i++ )
{
    test_data.push_back( i );
}

auto contains = []( const size_t a, const size_t b )
{
    if ( a == b )
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ( a == 3 )
    {
        return true;
    }
    if ( a == 33 && b != 30 && b != 31 && b != 3 )
    {
        return true;
    }
    if ( a == 10 && ( b == 26 || b == 27 ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    if ( a == 32 && b == 2 )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
std::random_shuffle( test_data.begin(), test_data.end() );
std::sort( test_data.begin(), test_data.end(), contains );
for ( const auto i : test_data )
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
for ( auto t = test_data.begin(); t < test_data.end(); t++ )
{
    for ( auto i = t; i < test_data.end(); i++ )
    {
        if ( contains( *i, *t ) )
        {
            std::cout << "Error " << *i << " contains " << *t << 
            std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

A result may be: 3
33
32
18
8
5
21
7
12
14
20
**27**
6
**10**
1
30
9
13
4
25
23
0
2
19
22
31
26
29
17
16
24
15
11
28

Error 10 contains 27

But I need to have 3 at top, 33 above all but (30, 31), 32 above 02 and **10** above (26, **27**)

Comment: What types are involved? Can you please make that into a [mre]? `contains` is almost never the correct comparison when you want a strict weak ordering btw. Please include the input container with sample data and the expected output.

Comment: You want [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)?

Comment: std::sort requires a `strick-weak-ordering` operator as the comparison operator. A classical less-than (`<`) will do this.  If you implement your own comparison make sure if obeys the requirements. See [C++ named requirements: Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) referenced from [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).  Without seeing a [mcve] it looks like your comparison operator does not meet the requirements.

Comment: its a little confusing that an object of some type can `contain` an object of same type. Perhaps a [mcve] would help to clarify, but as it currently stands the question cannot be answered

Comment: Thank you. I read the docu on ```compare``` and that is why I computed and printed the relation. I still do not see how my ```contains``` is not strict-weak-ordering.

Comment: @jochen Did you try your comparison function with the requirements for the `comp(a, b)` expression in the little box in the first link Richad linked to? For example, does `comp(a,a)==false` always hold? If you update your question with what I asked for in the first comment, someone will sort this out quickly.

Comment: Thanks for being frankly. The relation I postet was actually printed by my unittest. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: @ Jarod42 You are right, but I can still not see how my relation does not implement ```strict-weak-ordering```

Comment: I wrote a test to check the requirements of strict-weak ordering https://godbolt.org/z/vooKEx9cY. If I didnt miss something the comparator is fine. It just isnt the comparator you want.

Comment: you can check by writing a double loop on the resulting vector to see if `contains(x_i, x_j) == false;` for all `i >= j`

Comment: Okay, I've got it. Its in the docu of ```Compare```

Answer (score 1):

The relation is faulty in a strange way:

The documentation of `Compare` states:

`If equiv(a,b)==true and equiv(b,c)==true, then equiv(a,c)==true` **but**

```
equiv(32, 29) == true
equiv(29, 02) == true
equiv(32, 02) == false
```

So I do need topological ordering.